# Python PowerPoint SaveAs Task Scheduler

Tags: python, task, powerpoint, scheduler, win32com

I have automated the creation of a PowerPoint slide-deck via Python and have set-up a trigger in Task Scheduler for a daily report to be generated.

This is all fine while my computer is logged in, but the script fails when the setting: "Run whether is logged in or not".

I checked to see what line was at fault and it turns out it is this one:

```
Presentation.SaveAs('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test.pptx')
```

I am running Task Scheduler with highest priority but it only runs this task with the "User is logged in" state.

Below is the entire basic code segment for reference:

```
import win32com.client, MSO, MSPPT, sys, os
g = globals()
for c in dir(MSO.constants):    g[c] = getattr(MSO.constants, c)
for c in dir(MSPPT.constants):  g[c] = getattr(MSPPT.constants, c)

error_file = open('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\error_file.txt', 'wb')

run = False

try:
    Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("PowerPoint.Application")
    Application.Visible = True
    Presentation = Application.Presentations.Add()
    Slide = Presentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
    Presentation.SaveAs('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test.pptx')
    Presentation.Close()
    Application.Quit()
    run = True

except:
    run = False

if run == True:
    error_file.write('ok')
else:
    error_file.write('fail')
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
JP

Comment: I have also tried changing the SaveAs directory to just: "C:\\Users\\test.pptx" but still nothing happens and Task Scheduler exits with a 0x1.

Comment: I have also tried creating a folder within the "C:" drive called test, and giving everyone write privileges, but this does not work either.